# How to prove: Two solutions to pairwise known distances transformed either by rotation+translation or reflection+translation?

Tags: geometry, optimization, proof-writing, linear-transformations, classical-mechanics

For context, this result would be useful in carrying out practical attacks on [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3047212/213607) using [this idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3048962/213607).

I have tested this numerically and seems to work so often for me that I think it should be provable:

If I have 3 points in 2 dimensions which fulfill a distance equation with distance matrix:

$$D = \begin{bmatrix}0&d(p_1,p_2)&d(p_1,p_3)\\d(p_2,p_1)&0&d(p_2,p_3)\\d(p_3,p_1)&d(p_3,p_2)&0\end{bmatrix}$$

so that $$d(a,b)=<a,b>$$ with known $d(p_i,p_j)$ and $<a,b>$ being normal euclidean distance between $a$ and $b$. Can I prove that solution will be unique up to

1. translation + rotation
2. translation + reflection

[image]
[image]

How to prove that for two such given sets of 3 points fulfilling distance equations, one of those transformation between the sets can be found?

Comment: Transform both sets to a 2D coordinate system, where one point is at origin, another is on the positive $x$ axis at $(d_{12}, 0)$, and the third point is at $(u, v)$, with $v \ge 0$. Since $u$ and $v$ only depend on $d_{12}$, $d_{13}$, and $d_{23}$, the 2D coordinates are the same for the corresponding points in the two sets.  Then prove that this transformation is just rotation and/or reflection, by constructing the 3×3 corresponding orthonormal transformation matrices and the translation vectors.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I don't understand. Feel free to write an answer.

Comment: I am not a mathematician, so I don't prove stuff: I find the actual solutions.  I wrote the "algorithm" to find the required orthonormal rotation/reflection matrix and translation vector, which works whenever the point sets pairwise distances are positive (even when the points are collinear). However, that is not strictly speaking a proof that they exist, which means in the best case, a proper mathematician will come along, rewrite that as a proper proof, and downvote my answer (as it does not answer the stated question).  This is why I originally described it as a comment instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a mathematician, and I do not normally do proofs, as I only use math as a tool to find solutions to existing problems.  So, rather than show the proof, I show how to construct the actual rotation matrix and translation vector for arbitrary 3D point triplets with positive pairwise distances.

(I hope one of the mathematicians here can show how to condense this into a proper proof, as a separate answer.)

When you have three points
$$\bbox{
\vec{p}_1 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{matrix} \right ]
}, \quad \bbox{
\vec{p}_2 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2 \end{matrix} \right ]
}, \quad \bbox{
\vec{p}_3 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_3 \\ y_3 \\ z_3 \end{matrix} \right ]
}$$
with positive pairwise distances
$$\begin{aligned}
d_{12} &= \left\lVert\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1\right\rVert = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 + (z_2 - z_1)^2} \\
d_{13} &= \left\lVert\vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1\right\rVert = \sqrt{(x_3 - x_1)^2 + (y_3 - y_1)^2 + (z_3 - z_1)^2} \\
d_{23} &= \left\lVert\vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_2\right\rVert = \sqrt{(x_3 - x_2)^2 + (y_3 - y_2)^2 + (z_3 - z_2)^2} \\
\end{aligned}$$
you can construct a coordinate system where $\vec{p}_1$ is at origin, $\vec{p}_2$ is on the positive $x$ axis, and $\vec{p}_3$ is on the $xy$ plane on the positive $y$ side; i.e.
$$\bbox{
\vec{p}_1^\prime = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right ]
}, \quad \bbox{
\vec{p}_2^\prime = \left [ \begin{matrix} d_{12} \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right ]
}, \quad \bbox{
\vec{p}_3^\prime = \left [ \begin{matrix} u \\ v \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right ]
}$$
where
$$\bbox{\left\lbrace \; \begin{aligned}
u^2 + v^2 &= d_{13}^2 \\
(d_{12} - u)^2 + v^2 &= d_{23}^2
\end{aligned}\right .} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{ \left\lbrace \; \begin{aligned}
\displaystyle u &= \frac{d_{12}^2 + d_{13}^2 - d_{23}^2}{2 d_{12}} \\
\displaystyle v &= \sqrt{d_{13}^2 - u^2} \\
\end{aligned} \right .}$$
We can describe this transformation using an orthonormal matrix $\mathbf{M}$ and translation vector $\vec{t}$ as
$$\bbox{ \vec{p}^\prime = \mathbf{M} \left(\vec{p} - \vec{p}_1 \right) = \mathbf{M}\vec{p} + \vec{t} }$$
where
$$\bbox{ \vec{t} = -\mathbf{M} \vec{p}_1 }$$
and
$$\bbox{ \mathbf{M} = \left [ \begin{matrix}
m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13} \\
m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23} \\
m_{31} & m_{32} & m_{33} \end{matrix} \right ]} , \quad
\bbox{ \hat{u} = \left [ \begin{matrix} m_{11} \\ m_{12} \\ m_{13} \end{matrix} \right ]} , \quad \bbox{ \hat{v} = \left [ \begin{matrix} m_{21} \\ m_{22} \\ m_{23} \end{matrix} \right ]} , \quad \bbox{
\left [ \begin{matrix} m_{31} \\ m_{32} \\ m_{33} \end{matrix} \right ] = \hat{u} \times \hat{v} }$$
with
$$\bbox{ \left\lVert\hat{u}\right\rVert = \left\lVert\hat{v}\right\rVert = 1 },
\quad
\bbox{ \hat{u} \cdot \hat{v} = 0 }, \quad
\bbox{ \hat{u} = \frac{\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1}{\left\lVert\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1\right\rVert } }, \quad
\bbox{ \hat{v} = \frac{\vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1 - \hat{u} \left( \hat{u} \cdot \left ( \vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \right )}{\left\lVert \vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1 - \hat{u} \left( \hat{u} \cdot \left ( \vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \right ) \right\rVert} }$$
If we examine the matrix $\mathbf{M}$, we observe that it is orthonormal with determinant 1, and therefore a pure rotation matrix.

This means that if we have two such point triplets $\vec{p}_i$ and $\vec{q}_i$ with the same pairwise distance, and their corresponding rotation matrices $\mathbf{M}_1$ and $\mathbf{M}_2$, we find that
$$\mathbf{M}_1 ( \vec{p}_i - \vec{p}_1 ) = \mathbf{M}_2 ( \vec{q}_i - \vec{q}_1 )$$
because their transformed coordinates ($(0, 0, 0)$, $(d_{12}, 0, 0)$, and $(u, v, 0)$) are the same if their pairwise distances are the same. Reordering the terms we see that
$$\vec{p}_i = \mathbf{M}_1^{-1} \mathbf{M}_2 \vec{q}_i + \vec{p}_1 - \mathbf{M}_1^{-1} \mathbf{M}_2 \vec{q}_1$$
which can be written as
$$\vec{p}_i = \mathbf{R} \vec{q}_i + \vec{r}$$
where
$$\bbox{ \mathbf{R} = \mathbf{M}_1^{-1} \mathbf{M}_2 }, \quad
\bbox{ \vec{r} = \vec{p}_1 - \mathbf{R} \vec{q}_1 }$$
Thus, we have *constructed* the rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ and translation vector $\vec{r}$. Hopefully, its existence is proof enough.

Note that the above case is for the rotation only. However, if you change the third row vector of $\mathbf{M}$ into $\hat{v} \times \hat{u} = -\hat{u} \times \hat{v}$, its determinant will be -1, so it will be an "improper rotation matrix": a reflection.

Comment: Ok, well anyway, thanks for your input. I am also not a mathematician. As you can see on the animations I can also calculate the actual transformations between two solving sets (in something like 1023 of 1024 cases) and also "quite often" for 4,5 or 6 points. The point of asking would be to get some mathematicians' input of how to prove it is always possible for 3 points..

Comment: @mathreadler: Yup, that's exactly why I thought a comment was more appropriate.